# Banner help in CSS and HTML

Tags: css, html, wrapper, banner

I have a header div tag background, and I'm trying to put the banner div tag over it so it would show the image. but it's not showing up. I don't know how to fix it.

Header tag CSS:

```
#header-wrapper
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 650x;
        background: #659EC7 url(images/overlay.png) repeat;
    }

    #header
    {
    }
```

Banner tag CSS:

```
#banner
{
background: url(images/banner.png);
}
```

And here's my Header HTML Code. I placed the banner div tag inside it:

```
<body>
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header" class="container">
            <div id="banner">
        </div>
        <div id="logo">
            <span class="icon icon-fire"></span>
            <h1><a href="#">EXO</a></h1> </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.php?page=home" title="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?page=gallery" title="">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?page=contact" title="">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?page=logreg" title="">Login/Register</a></li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Please help me! THanks :)

Comment: what is your expected output??

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian A visible header. Its because there height and width isn't set. Check my answer.

Comment: @Ruddy i have checked your answer buddy, exactly i got the same answer but you posted it so i didn't post the answer, but after checking kichen's comment got confused whether i misunderstood the question, so asked his clarification, what he needs actually

Comment: @kichen : what exactly u need?? all seems pretty fine to me => http://jsfiddle.net/hq83e/1/

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian Im pretty sure we are correct :)

Comment: @Ruddy if it is correct my upvote is waiting for you.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the image as a background on `.banner`. But it has no width or height. Try:

```
#banner {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: url(images/banner.png);
}
```

Use this one if `.banner` parent has a height, If not -

---

```
#banner {
   width: 100%;
   height: 80px;
   background: url(images/banner.png);
}
```

We can use this, setting the width and height for `.banner`.

---

Background images do not set width and height so without them the `div` is not shown.

You also haven't given `.header` any height and width. So for my `width: 100%;` & `height: 100%;` to work you would need to set that. Or just set `.banner` width and height in `px`

Also for the header-wrapper you haven't put `px` (maybe a typo).

```
#header-wrapper {
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 650px;
      background: #659EC7 url(images/overlay.png) repeat;
 }
```

**Setting width and height on `.banner`.**

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/hH6K7/)

**Setting width and height on `.banner`,`.header` and the wrap.**

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/hH6K7/1/)

Comment: didn't do it either. :(

Comment: Look at my demos and you will be able to see it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a width and height to your banner div.

```
#banner{
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
}
```

Note that the height have to be fixed for this to work.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8syUX/